# How do you set up kubernetes RBAC resources so that pods can access the API via a client?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rbac

#### Problem

I have a simple RBAC configuration to access the Kubernetes API in-cluster. However I am getting what appears to be conflicting information from `kubectl`. After deploying the manifest, it appears that RBAC is set up properly.

```
$ kubectl exec -ti pod/controller -- kubectl auth can-i get namespaces
Warning: resource 'namespaces' is not namespace scoped
yes
```

However, actually making the request yields a permission error

```
$ kubectl exec -ti pod/controller -- kubectl get namespaces
Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:controller" cannot list resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope
command terminated with exit code 1
```

#### Manifest

```
apiVersion: 'v1'
kind: 'ServiceAccount'
metadata:
  name: 'controller'
---

apiVersion: 'rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1'
kind: 'Role'
metadata:
  name: 'read-namespaces'
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - 'namespaces'
    verbs:
      - 'get'
      - 'watch'
      - 'list'
---

apiVersion: 'rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1'
kind: 'RoleBinding'
metadata:
  name: 'read-namespaces'
roleRef:
  apiGroup: ''
  kind: 'Role'
  name: 'read-namespaces'
subjects:
  - kind: 'ServiceAccount'
    name: 'controller'
---

apiVersion: 'v1'
kind: 'Pod'
metadata:
  name: 'controller'
  labels:
    'app': 'controller'
spec:
  containers:
    - name: 'kubectl'
      image: 'bitnami/kubectl:latest'
      imagePullPolicy: 'Always'
      command:
        - 'sleep'
        - '3600'
  serviceAccountName: 'controller'
---
```

#### Other Info

I've tried `kubectl auth reconcile -f manifest.yaml` as well as `kubectl apply -f manifest.yaml` and the results are the same.

I've also set "read-namespaces" `RoleBinding.subjects[0].namespace` to the  proper namespace ("default" in this case). No change in output.

Comment: Roles are per namespace, you need to create a cluster role

Comment: Can namespaces only be accessed by cluster roles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespace is a cluster scoped resource. So you need a `ClusterRole` and a `ClusterRoleBinding`.

```
apiVersion: 'rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1'
kind: 'ClusterRole'
metadata:
  name: 'read-namespaces'
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - 'namespaces'
    verbs:
      - 'get'
      - 'watch'
      - 'list'
---

apiVersion: 'rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1'
kind: 'ClusterRoleBinding'
metadata:
  name: 'read-namespaces'
roleRef:
  apiGroup: 'rbac.authorization.k8s.io'
  kind: 'ClusterRole'
  name: 'read-namespaces'
subjects:
  - kind: 'ServiceAccount'
    name: 'controller'
---
```

Answer (score 2):

Roles are per namespace, you need to create a cluster role  and binding using `ClusterRoleBinding`

If you want to bind your cluster role to specific namespace, you could do something like this, using RoleBinding on a ClusterRole:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sa
  namespace: myapp

---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: role-myapp
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - batch
  resources:
  - cronjobs
  verbs:
  - create
  - delete
  - deletecollection
  - get
  - list
  - patch
  - update
  - watch

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: job001
  namespace: myapp
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: role-myapp
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: sa
  namespace: myapp
```

Comment: I was able to get this to work, but I also needed to change the RoleBinding to a ClusterRoleBinding